# Tried to register two views with the same name GestureHandlerRootView when running as dev-client

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I started my React Native Expo application as "**--dev-client**" and it throws me the following messages:

**"**react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..)**."**

**"Tried to register two views with the same name GestureHandlerRootView"**

If I run the app in expo go, everything works fine.

**I guess the problem will be somewhere with React Navigation**

**My packages:**

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
"@types/react": "^18.0.17",
"ansi-styles": "^6.1.0",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"expo": "~44.0.0",
"expo-app-auth": "~11.1.0",
"expo-apple-authentication": "~4.1.0",
"expo-build-properties": "^0.3.0",
"expo-calendar": "~10.1.0",
"expo-cli": "^6.0.6",
"expo-dev-client": "~0.8.6",
"expo-facebook": "~12.1.0",
"expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
"expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
"firebase": "9.7.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"patch-package": "^6.4.7",
"postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react-native-actions-sheet-picker": "^0.3.5",
"react-native-circular-progress-indicator": "^4.4.0",
"react-native-dashed-line": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
"react-native-loading-skeleton": "^1.0.1",
"react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
"react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-open-maps": "^0.4.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^2.0.4",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-step-indicator-v2": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
"react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
"react-native-web": "0.17.1",
"react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
"react-use": "^17.4.0",
"twrnc": "^3.4.0",
"yarn": "^1.22.19"}
```